# How to merge two tables MySQL-PHP with date sorting

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, union

I want to merge the results of two tables in to one.
Please refer the following tables :

```
    Data from microblog table as Row array
    Array ( [ID] => 46 [userID] => 1 [userNAME] => user [blog_content] => HAI DEAR [page_name] => honda [page_ID] => 31 [post_time] => 2011-10-18 11:06:54 )
 Data from Page_review table as Row array
    Array ( [page_review_id] => 5 [page_id] => 31 [page_review_by_id] => 31 [page_review_by_username] => user [page_review_time] => 2011-10-18 11:43:34 [page_review_content] => hai )
```

Table Microblog MySQL query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `featurezme_store`.`microblog`;
CREATE TABLE  `featurezme_store`.`microblog` (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `userNAME` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
  `page_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `page_ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `post_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=48 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Table page_review

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `featurezme_store`.`page_review`;
CREATE TABLE  `featurezme_store`.`page_review` (
  `page_review_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `page_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_review_by_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `page_review_by_username` varchar(145) NOT NULL,
  `page_review_time` datetime NOT NULL,
  `page_review_content` varchar(555) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`page_review_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

the table Microblog is used to store blog posts & page_review is used to store reviews about pages[Microblog's are in pages].

My requirement is i want to show Blogposts & page reviews sorted by Date [post_time in Microblog & page_review_time on page_review].

how can i do this ? please help me.

Comment: How are these related, i.e. what do they link on? The `page_id` and `page_ID` fields?

Comment: yes,they are,on microblog page_ID indicates that which page user posting posts,on page?_review - which page commenting review.

Comment: i think i need something like this `SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'post' AS type, ID, userID, blog_content, create_time FROM microblog where page_ID=33
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'review' AS type, page_review_id, page_id,  page_review_content,  create_time FROM page_review where page_id=33
) T1
ORDER BY create_time desc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I have updated my answear, you can use union as you wanted.

Just have the same number of fields and because the results are placed the one unde the other use fields that make sense to be the one under the other. This example will bring all blogs and reviews created by a specific user (if page_review_by_id actually refers to the user id) and related to a specific page.

```
( 
SELECT  
`microblog`.`userID`, 
`microblog`.`blog_content` as `blog or review`, 
`microblog`.`post_time`, 
`microblog`.`page_id` 
from `microblog`
where `microblog`.`page_id`='1' and `microblog`.`userID`='1' 
)
union
( 
SELECT  
`page_review`.`page_review_by_id`, 
`page_review`.`page_review_content`, 
`page_review`.`page_review_time`, 
`page_review`.`page_id`
from `page_review`
where `page_review`.`page_id`='1' and `page_review`.`page_review_by_id`='1' 
)
```

======== Edit== Suggesting a schema with foreign keys ================

Because I don't see any foreign keys in your schema if I could suggest optionaly a schema that applies foreign keys I present one below.

These rules are supported by this schema:

- Blogs belong to the site and not to the user so there is not on delete cascade applied.
- Blogs are created by users and a foreign key is applied so when a user id is inserted the consistency is assured through the foreign key.
- The same goes for the page, a foreign key is applid without on delte cascade.
- The same goes for the reviews table
- If a user or page is deleted no child row is deleted

  /*******************Create* ******* *****/
  CREATE TABLE  `user` (
    `user_id` int  unsigned NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` varchar(16) NOT NULL, 
    `userpassword` BLOB,
    PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  CREATE TABLE  `page` (
    `page_id` mediumint  unsigned NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `title` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`page_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB   DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  CREATE TABLE  `microblog` (
    `blog_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `blog_content` text NOT NULL,
    `date_created` datetime NOT NULL, 
    `author_id` int unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `page_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL, 
    PRIMARY KEY (`blog_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `blogfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`)
          REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
          /*NO ON DELETE CASCADE*/
      CONSTRAINT `blogfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`)
          REFERENCES `page` (`page_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

  CREATE TABLE  `page_review` (
    `review_id` int unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
    `review_content` varchar(555) NOT NULL, 
    `date_created` datetime NOT NULL,
    `author_id` int unsigned NOT NULL, 
    `page_id` mediumint unsigned NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`review_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `reviewfk1` FOREIGN KEY (`author_id`)
          REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`),
          /*NO ON DELETE CASCADE*/
      CONSTRAINT `reviewfk2` FOREIGN KEY (`page_id`)
          REFERENCES `page` (`page_id`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
  /************************** ********/

  /****** ****Insertions********** **/
  INSERT INTO  `user` ( `username`,`userpassword`)
  VALUES ('username11', AES_ENCRYPT('password1',
  'encription_key') ),
   ('username22', AES_ENCRYPT('password2',
  'encription_key') );

  INSERT INTO `page` ( `title`) VALUES
  ('title1'),('title2');

  INSERT INTO `microblog` (`blog_content`,`date_created`,
  `author_id`,`page_id`) VALUES
  ('blogcontent1','2011-2-2 12:00','1','1'),
  ('blogcontent2','2011-2-2 12:00','2','2');

  INSERT INTO `page_review` (`review_content`,
  `date_created`,`author_id`,`page_id`) VALUES
  ('reviewcontent1','2011-2-2 12:00','1','1'),
  ('reviewcontent2','2011-2-2 12:00','2','2');
  /************* ***********/

  /*************** Queries ******* /
  /*Help on Identifing a user*/
  SELECT `username` 
  FROM `user` WHERE `username` ='username22'
  and `userpassword`=AES_ENCRYPT('password2','encription_key')

  ( 
  SELECT
  `microblog`.`blog_content` as `blog or content`, 
  `microblog`.`date_created`, 
  `microblog`.`author_id`, 
  `microblog`.`page_id` 
  from `microblog`
  where `microblog`.`author_id`='1' and `microblog`.`page_id`='1' 
  )
  union
  ( 
  SELECT
  `page_review`.`review_content`, 
  `page_review`.`date_created`, 
  `page_review`.`author_id`, 
  `page_review`.`page_id`
  from `page_review`
  where `page_review`.`author_id`='1' and `page_review`.`page_id`='1' 
  )

Comment: thank you,but i need it like History,means a user commented on a post,review a page like that.i tried above with changing page id,but i retrieves  a huge collection .

Comment: `SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT 'post' AS type, ID, userID, blog_content, create_time FROM microblog where page_ID=33
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'review' AS type, page_review_id, page_id,  page_review_content,  create_time FROM page_review where page_id=33
) T1
ORDER BY create_time desc` i need something like this,

Comment: ,Really thank to you ,it is a great Answer,Actually this is not a Blog Project and with your help i managed it to work,really i am little bit confused because the table user_pages have some other meaning too,it depends.Cheer up...